# How to clamp a float in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a number 1.00000001, and I want to clamp it between -1 and 1 to avoid *input out of range error* on `ACOS()` function. An MCVE look like this:

```
SELECT ACOS( 1 + 0.0000000001 );
```

My ideal would be something like:

```
SELECT ACOS( CLAMP(1 + 0.0000000001, -1, 1) );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I found was:

```
SELECT ACOS(GREATEST(-1, LEAST(1, 1 + 0.0000000001));
```

Comment: I would love to see a CLAMP function though. And I am not sure about perf issues, this is on a critical request

Comment: That's as fast as it gets unless you want to write a C function (which is a viable option if there is a premium on performance).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe in fact, could you maybe add an answer with that C function you are talking about? I think that would be pretty useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- example: clamp(subject, min, max)
CREATE FUNCTION clamp(integer, integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    AS 'select GREATEST($2, LEAST($3, $1));'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

-- example: clamp_above(subject, max)
CREATE FUNCTION clamp_above(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    AS 'select LEAST($1, $2);'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

-- example: clamp_below(subject, min)
CREATE FUNCTION clamp_below(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    AS 'select GREATEST($1, $2);'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Comment: Quite an interesting answer! However IMHO both CLAMP_BELOW and CLAMP_ABOVE are not clearer than LEAST and GREATEST. And I would love to have that function but not to have to add it to every single PG database I want to work on. +1 for the idea though

Answer (score 0):

Following [PG documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html), we can
create the simple function below:

```c
#include "postgres.h"
include "fmgr.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

/* by value */

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(clamp);

Datum
clamp(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32 num = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
    int32 min = PG_GETARG_INT32(1);
    int32 max = PG_GETARG_INT32(2);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(num < min ? min : (num > max ? max : num));
}
```

And then compile it and move it to the package lib directory (done on a Mac):

```bash
cc -I$(pg_config --includedir-server)  -c pg_clamp.c
cc -bundle -flat_namespace -o pg_clamp.so pg_clamp.o
mv pg_clamp.so $(pg_config --pkglibdir)
rm pg_clamp.o
```

Finally, reference it in SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clamp(int, int, int) RETURNS int AS 'pg_clamp', 'clamp' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```